# format date column when select query

Tags: php, mysql, select, date-format

This is my date data ;
From : 09-01-2013
To : 22-01-2013 (*the format is fixed*)

how to format for column date `send_date_time` to `d-m-Y` .. below is my query:

```
$filter = "and DATE_FORMAT(send_date_time,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '08-01-2012 12:00:00' and '22-01-2013 12:00:00' ";
```

but above query is failed when i try with this(*below*) query, yes can work:

```
$filter = "and send_date_time BETWEEN '2013-01-08 12:00:00' and '2013-01-22 12:00:00' ";
```

Full query

```
$get_transaction_history  = ("select * from `sms_sendlog` where store_id='".$store."' ".$filter." order by id desc");
```

Column:

```
Colum Name : send_date_time
e.g  value : 2012-10-22 10:19:36
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like

```
$filter = "and send_date_time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('08-01-2012 12:00:00','%d-%m-%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT('22-01-2013 12:00:00','%d-%m-%Y') ";
```

[Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: Thanks @Dasun .. i found we can convert the data first date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_from)); before put in query too ..

Answer (score 0):

Use **STR_TO_DATE** function instead of using **DATE_FORMAT** function.

Try this:

```
$filter = "and send_date_time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08-01-2012 12:00:00','%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('22-01-2013 12:00:00','%d-%m-%Y') ";
```

Check this link [**MySQL Date Time Function: STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)